# Can I use grails to somehow emit data with anonymous javascript functions

Tags: grails, extjs

I would like to have a controller emit a JSON response with something like this:

```
{
    sidebar: {
        xtype: "container",
        flex: 1,
        bodyCls: "my-sidebar",
        itemId: "my-sidebar-container",
        items: [
        {
            xtype: "panel",
            animCollapse: false,
            collapseFirst: false,
            collapsed: false,
            collapsible: true,
            flex: 1,
            bodyCls: "my-sidebar-message-section",
            itemId: "my-sidebar-message-section-container",
            html: "<h1>Messages (2)</h1><p>Bank will be closed on September 4th, 2013 for Labor Day</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://google.com">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>",
            listeners: {
                 boxready: function(p) {
                      alert('Hi');
                 }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

In my Grails controller I define it like this:

```
package com.fourgablesguy.myapp

import grails.converters.JSON

class SidebarController {

def generateSideBar() {
    def sidebarItems = [
            [
                xtype: 'panel',
                animCollapse: false,
                collapseFirst: false,
                collapsed: false,
                collapsible: true,
                flex: 1,
                bodyCls: 'my-sidebar-message-section',
                itemId: 'my-sidebar-message-section-container',
                html: messageSectionHtml,
                listeners: [
                    boxready: "function(p) { alert('Hi');}"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    [
     xtype: 'container',
     flex: 1,
     bodyCls: 'my-sidebar',
     itemId: 'my-sidebar-container',
     items: sidebarItems
    ]
}
```

However the grails.converters.JSON converts my function() definition to a string so the actual JSON that is emitted by the controller action has a string for the function():

```
{
    sidebar: {
        xtype: "container",
        flex: 1,
        bodyCls: "my-sidebar",
        itemId: "my-sidebar-container",
        items: [
        {
            xtype: "panel",
            animCollapse: false,
            collapseFirst: false,
            collapsed: false,
            collapsible: true,
            flex: 1,
            bodyCls: "my-sidebar-message-section",
            itemId: "my-sidebar-message-section-container",
            html: "<h1>Messages (2)</h1><p>Bank will be closed on September 4th, 2013 for Labor Day</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://google.com">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>",
            listeners: {
                 boxready: "function(p) {alert('Hi');}"
                 }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

The specific issue is this line:
**boxready: "function(p) {alert('Hi');}"**
I would like to know a way to instead return the above as:
**boxready: function(p) {alert('Hi');}**

This is not really "object data" I am trying to return in JSON, I can understand if this is not possible.

Comment: I would suggest not going this way; it may look seductive for simpler functions like above, but for anything just a bit more complex it will soon turn into maintenance nightmare. What's the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Alexander See my comments in the answer from Grooveek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a close look at [json.org](http://www.json.org/), you'll see that JSON is a data exchange format, and that types allowed in JSON does not include `Function` or function declaration. If there is a `function`, that's not JSON anymore, that's javascript. You'll never have a JSON converter that will allow to pass functions in it (if you don't hack it to do so)

If you want to transmit a function to your controller, why not passing the name, and parameters of the function to call, which would be defined in a separate javascript file.

Comment: JSON does not allow functions due to security reason.

Comment: Thanks for this help, to do a workaround I am following @dbrin advice and moving listener functionality to a controller.

 `    Ext.define('SB.controller.Home', { `
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        init: function(application) {
            Ext.ns('SB.home.utils');
            SB.home.utils.moveHeaderTools = function(p) {
                alert('Hi');
            };

        this.control({
            '#my-sidebar-message-section-container': {
                boxready: SB.home.utils.moveHeaderTools
            }
        });
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Alexander Tokarev's answer here but would like to suggest that if you absolutely need to return view classes from the server make them dumb. Config only. Move all of the functionality and listeners to a client side controller.